# How to save image to Document Directory from local file in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I want to save an image from local folder(like Module/assets/ImageName.png) in my project into Document Directory. I am using the 'react-native-fs' library for the same.

Code is below:

```
componentWillMount() {
    var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
    var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ImageName.png';
    // write the file
    RNFS.writeFile(path, './Module/assets/ImageName.png', 'utf8') // what to use inplace of utf8?
      .then((success) => {
        console.log(path);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    }
```

Please suggest how should I proceed?
Thanks.

Comment: you should use moveFile  : https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#movefilefilepath-string-destpath-string-promisevoid

Answer (score 0):

For `images` included via `Xcode asset catalogs`  use the image name without the extension:

```js
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ImageName.png';
RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS('ImageName.png', path, 100, 100)
      .then(results => {
        console.log('Copy File', results);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error copying file', err);
      });
```

Comment: it is giving an error "Failed to fetch PHAsset with local identifier ImageName.png" with no error message".